# Word for the tragic hero's journey

Tags: single-word-requests, story

I'm looking for a word that describes the tragic hero's journey. Basically I want a word that parallels the word "odyssey" but entails a tragic fall at the end. The way I want to use this word is in

> Winston* embarks upon a tragic _____, eventually dying as an individual

I've considered using the word "odyssey" but to me that sounds wrong and connotes a sense of an epic hero, whereas I'm arguing Winston* is a tragic hero.

*For context, Winston is the main character from George Orwell's *1984*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that Winston appears to end the story having given up his quest, and succumbed to the establishment (almost?) entirely, several things spring to mind:

- @Brad’s answer above is good enough (it is a journey)
- It’s really more of a ***descent*** than a pilgrimage
- His downfall suggests ***antihero*** (possibly hyphenated) is a better term for the protagonist
- In fact, ***downfall*** might be a good term for his arc
- You could do worse than start with [*downfall*](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/downfall) in a thesaurus and look at a few of its near neighbours

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a simple JOURNEY would fit the bill

Answer (score 0):

Here are some words that you may use in this situation:

- **voyage**
- **traversal**
- **pilgrimage**

I would use the latter if your hero is on a journey for a noble intent.

Answer (score 0):

Winston embarks upon a tragic **wandering**, eventually dying as an individual. (or even *maunder* - an aimless wander [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/maunder))

He embarks on his guts, wanders, is ensnared and he and his cause suffer for it.

> **wandering** [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/wandering)
>
> traveling about without any clear destination “she followed him in
>   his wanderings and looked after him”
>
> Synonyms:
>       roving, vagabondage
>
> Types:
>       drifting
>       aimless wandering from place to place
>
> Type of:
>       travel, traveling, traveling
>       the act of going from one place to another
>
> adj having no fixed course “his life followed a wandering course”
>
> Synonyms:
>       erratic
>
> ```
> unsettled
> not settled or established
> ```

Comment: Tragic or not, the Hero’s Journey has a definite purpose to it, and in order to become a Hero they have to have some purpose by the end of it, so this isn't really appropriate. Even if the protagonist isn’t aware of it(!)

Comment: @WillCrawford is 1984 really a tragic journey though?

Comment: @tox123 not really up to me, OP used the word “tragic” in his question. But I think so, yes — Winston ultimately fails and his rebellious determination is quelled. [*Not with a bang but a whimper*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hollow_Men) is apposite.